# Data being overwritten rabbitmq excel

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, phpexcel, amqp

I am using rabbitmq queue for getting data from a controller and then consumer service process the data and produces excel sheet using php-excel.

The issue i am facing is that the data is getting overwritten in excel sheets if only one consumer is run. If i run multiple consumers, the issue is mostly resolved.

I am using direct as rabbitmq type and luiggio excel bundle for symfony2.

Did anyone ever has a similar problem? Any hints about possible issue are welcome.

//part of consumer code

```
public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg)
    {
        $data = array();
        $data = unserialize($msg->body);

        if ($data['type'] == 'sometype') {
                $this->excel->excelObj->getProperties()->setCreator("something");
                $value = $this->excel->excelObj->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
                $value->setCellValue('A1', 'Some Number');
                $value->setCellValue('B1', 'Some Other Number');
                $incr = 2;
                foreach ($data['somedata'] as $datum) {
                  value->setCellValue('A'.$incr, $datum['that_number']);
                  value->setCellValue('B'.$incr, $datum['that_number']);
                }
        } else if ($data['type'] == 'sometype2') {
                $this->excel->excelObj->getProperties()->setCreator("something");
                $value = $this->excel->excelObj->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
                $value->setCellValue('A1', 'Some Number2');
                $incr = 2;
                foreach ($data['somedata'] as $datum) {
                  value->setCellValue('A'.$incr, $datum['that_number']);
                }
        }

        $this->excel->excelObj->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
        $this->excel->excelObj->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $tempName = $data['type'] .microtime(). '.xls';
        $this->excel->getStreamWriter()->write('/tmp/'.$tempName);
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to show some code if you want to get feedback.

Comment: sure, adding the sample code in a min

Comment: @hakre added sample code

Comment: Just a guess, do you need to reinitialize $this->excel->excelObj with each call to execute()?

Comment: So after seeing your code it's not clear to me what you mean by that "data gets overwritten". The files? Inside the file, e.g. some specific Cells? If so which one? And you don't do file-locking, you probably want that to ensure that you don't get any race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the PHP excel object being created.

Finally resolved it by initiating/resetting the excel object forcefully after one excel sheet is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the fact that you're not incrementing $incr within your `foreach` loops, so you're always writing to the same row; and `value` should be `$value` within those loops as well.

```
$value->setCellValue('A'.$incr++, $datum['that_number']);
```